# Custom colors in r shinydashboard package

Tags: r, shiny, shinydashboard

*I'm wondering if there exists some tricks out there to customize the colors available through the `shinydashboard` package?*

---

As the [documentation](https://rstudio.github.io/shinydashboard/appearance.html) suggests, there are only a small number of colors available. Still I'm wondering (and hoping) that there are some tricks to customize that palette, preferably using RGB colors (like `#123456`).

Is there such a magic trick out there? Or is there another package similar to `shinydashboard`, that allows customizing colors?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[library(fresh)](https://github.com/dreamRs/fresh) allows this degree of customization (the convenient way) regarding `library(shinydashboard)` or `library(shinydashboardPlus)`:

```
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)
library(fresh)

mytheme <- create_theme(
  adminlte_color(
    light_blue = "#434C5E"
  ),
  adminlte_sidebar(
    width = "400px",
    dark_bg = "#D8DEE9",
    dark_hover_bg = "#81A1C1",
    dark_color = "#2E3440"
  ),
  adminlte_global(
    content_bg = "#FFF",
    box_bg = "#D8DEE9", 
    info_box_bg = "#D8DEE9"
  )
)

ui <- dashboardPage(
  dashboardHeader(),
  dashboardSidebar(),
  dashboardBody(
    use_theme(mytheme)
  )
)

server <- function(input, output) { }

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Also see this [related article](https://rinterface.github.io/shinydashboardPlus/articles/more-skins.html#fresh).

Comment: do you know is there a way to change the font size using `fresh` for `shinydashboard`? When I use `fresh::bs_vars_font(size_base = "25px")` in `create_theme`, I get an error saying `Error: You cannot mix Bootstrap and AddminLTE variables`. Do you know of any workaround? Cheers

Comment: @user63230 please run `search_vars_adminlte2()` for a full list of available adminlte2 variables. You can set them via `fresh::adminlte_vars()`. However, it seems there are no font size variables available. I guess you'll need to use css directly: `div(style = "font-size: 40px;")`. You might want to ask a separate question if needed.